# Flow of registration between kafka and zookeeper

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, registration

I have some problems when trying to dockerize kafka and zookeeper.

So could you guys help me to understand the flow between kafka and zookeeper by diagrams or something ? Does zookeeper need connection of port 9092 from kafka server ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka uses Zookeeper as a distributed resource to keep in sync the metadata that Kafka actors (producers, consumers) needs to know. But Kafka uses Zookeeper, not vice-versa. Thus, the connections between Kafka and Zookeeper will be created Kafka talking to Zookeeper's port 2181 (default Zookeeper' service port). Port 9092 (or formerly 6667) are ports that Kafka brokers (a.k.a. Kafka servers) uses to accept connection and for getting/sending messages, but these ports have nothing to do at all to Zookeeper.